# How to Print environment variable in execle() using echo?

Tags: c, unix, system-calls

I tried this code.

```
char *env[]={"first=one","second=two","third=three",NULL};

execle("/bin/echo","echo","$first","$second","$third",(char *)0,env);
```

It gives output

```
$first $second $third
```

Clearly this is not what I am expecting. Is their any way to print environment variables using echo?

I gets the variables using printenv. If it relates.

```
 execle("/usr/bin/printenv","printenv","first","second","third",(char *)0,env);
```

Output:

```
one
two
three
```

Comment: It is the *shell* that does variable substitution using e.g. `$first`. It's not something the commands themselves or the operating system does for you.

Comment: `int *env[]={..."` why on earth pointers to `int` here?

Comment: its `char *env[]`. typing mistake..

Comment: @ Some programmer dude got it. thanks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Command line expansions are provided by shell before the command is called. To get the expansion as expected you can exec shell with "-c" option and whole command line to be executed.

```
execle("/bin/bash","bash", "-c", "echo $first $second $third",(char *)0,env);
```